# How to make view model of table using edo and non-edo attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am have a table 'summands' in DB. Table have 3 columns: id(PK), summand1 and summand2.
I am need to show in view table with columns summand1, summand2 and summ.
I know how make view for summands with entity framework, but I have one more column, which didnt exist in a DB. And I don't understand how to connect DB with my class and have usefull interface.

I want to have interface like this:
Model:

```
namespace MyProject.Models 
    { 
        public class ExpressionTable 
        {
            public List<Expression> Expressions{ get; set; }
        }
        public class Expression 
        { 
            public int summand1 { get; set; } 
            public int summand2 { get; set; }
            public int summ{ get; set; }
        } 
    }
```

And in view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.ExpressionTable
<table>
<thead><tr>
   <th>summand1</th> <th>summand2</th> <th>summ</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Expressions.ToList()) {
   <tr>
   <td>@item.summand1</td> <td>@item.summand2</td> <td>@item.summ</td>
   </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

And where I must calculate summ?
Thanks!

Comment: how your linq query. so that we can see

Comment: In this example i dont know how to do it. This is part of my question.